# How do I add citations using rmarkdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, citations

I am having some trouble getting citations to work in rmarkdown.
I use `write_bib()` to generate a bibliography file which seems to work.

```
knitr::write_bib("knitr", "package.bib")
```

```
@Manual{R-knitr,
  title = {knitr: A General-Purpose Package for Dynamic Report Generation in R},
  author = {Yihui Xie},
  year = {2020},
  note = {R package version 1.29},
  url = {https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=knitr},
}
```

However when I try to use this in the document like this.

```
---
title: "Example"
output: html_document
Bibliography: package.bib
---

[@R-knitr]
```

I get this

[image: No Citation]

I think I am missing something but I cannot work out what it is.
Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Try with `bibliography: package.bib` (instead of `Bibliography: package.bib`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rmarkdown metadata [are formatted in YAML](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/html-document.html), which is case sensitive. The correct format would be

```
---
title: "Example"
output: html_document
bibliography: package.bib
---
```

Comment: Thanks that was it! I knew it would be something so simple but I have been staring at this for hours and could not find it!